# List shifting in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, list

So basicly what I want is,

I am passing one array in List component like this :

<List items={["A", "B", "C"]} />

Now I need to print each element in list like this :

●   A
●   B
●   C

But whenever someone will click any list element, that element should come at the 1st place.
Example : if I clicked B, then output should look like this :

●   B
●   A
●   C

Any solution for this, please help.

Comment: what have you tried so far ?

Comment: use a state to hold your array, when you want to change the order, clone the array, make the modification on the new array, update state to the new array

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/328193)  You are encouraged to make an attempt.  If during your attempt you encounter a specific problem, such as a specific operation producing an error or an unexpected result, we can help with that.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this

```
const List = ({items}) => {
  const [list, setList] = useState(items)

  
   return <ul>{list.map((l, i) => 
               <li  
                 onClick={() => setList([l, ...items.filter(item => item !== l)])} 
                 key={i}>
                 {l}
               </li>)}
   </ul>

}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, this one was short and simple.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a copy of the value you want to move.
2. Create a copy of your array without the value using `filter`. or `splice` if you have the index.
3. Add the value to the Array copy using `unshift`
4. Set your state to the Array copy

Doc :
https://love2dev.com/blog/javascript-remove-from-array/
[https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unshift.asp#:~:text=The%20unshift()%20method%20adds,method%20overwrites%20the%20original%20array](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unshift.asp#:%7E:text=The%20unshift()%20method%20adds,method%20overwrites%20the%20original%20array).

Answer (score 0):

```js
   const Home = () => {
    const [myList, setMyList] = useState(["A","B","C"]);


    function shiftPlace(from, to) {
        const arr = myList;
        let cutOut = arr.splice(from, 1)[0];
        arr.splice(to, 0, cutOut);
        setMyList([...arr]);
    }

    return (<div>
        {
            myList.map((v, i) => {
                return <span key={i} onClick={() => {
                    shiftPlace(i, 0);
                }}>{v}</span>;
            })
        }
    </div>);
};
```

This does everything you need.